# how can i restore my database with new name

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have a backup file from my main DB(IDTDB) that called MainDBBackup.bak and i want to restore it with another name.but i recieve this error:
"the logical file 'IDTDB_Log' is not part of database 'newDB'.use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list logical file names.restore database terminated abnormally.change database context to master."

i used this code to restore my database:
"use master;restore filelistonly from disk=N'my backup file path'; restore database newDB from disk=N'my backup file path' with file=1,replace,nounload,stats=10;"

note: it is important for me to have a new database with new name.

i have created a new database and its tables by execute a sql query and tried to restore my mainDB to it but i recieved that error again.

Comment: I'm not seeing the C# tag, and I'm thinking this is more a server admin issue then a programming problem

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi by voting on answers that you find useful, and selecting one that you find to be an acceptable solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Using SSMS you can create a new database and then restore to that from your backup. You will need to set the option overwrite existing database.

Comment: i set this option already.i solved that problem and i restored my database with new name. but when i tried to use restored database i recieved another error:"database 'newdb' cannot be opened.It is in the middle of a restore"!

Comment: In SSMS in the options window was the radio button "RESTORE WITH RECOVERY" selected? The text next to this button says it will leave the database "ready to use" whereas the other options leave the database "non-operational" and "read only" respectively